# How to use wroker threads in nodejs to make the code excute faster?

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, electron, node-worker-threads

I have a js file that contains multiple functions inside it, that can be exported to other js files and then I do some tasks. but the issue is there are some functions that take so much time like there is a function that renames thousands of files on a **file system** that totally blocks the electron UI for 30 seconds.
here is how my file looks like:

```
const someModules = require("some-nodejs-modules");

function async first_CpuIntensive_Func(){
//some cpu intensive tasks
//some regexps
return someData;
}
function async second_CpuIntensive_Func(){
//some cpu intensive tasks
//some regexps
return someData;
}




module.exports = {first_CpuIntensive_Func,second_CpuIntensive_Func}
```

I am new to **nodejs** **worker threads** need help. Or is there any solution besides worker threads?

Answer (score 0):

0. Your functions are not async in your example, update your knowledge [async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
1. You may want to use async fs wrapper [MZ\FS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mz) awailable in npm to make asyncronous file reads\writes
2. If you really need worker threads (which is a pretty complicated topic) then you just read the docs concerning [NodeJs cluster module](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html)

Comment: I am using the async functions of the fs module.

Comment: Well, this doesn't come out from your examples.

Comment: It is just a general example.

Comment: If i call one of the functions it should run in a separate thread instead of using the single thread.

Comment: 1. You do not need to run it in separate thread since async functions are non-blocking.
2. If you really need to use multithreading, then you fire up master worker, invoke task there and distribute this task to multiple workers on your logic (i.e. by file folders, or file dates). Workers fulfill their tasks and return result to master. It all works in tree pattern ierarchy.  There are plenty examples if you google it.

Comment: let me use the master worke.